# why do I have to DNS.1 = localhost in my certificate SAN for chrome to accept it

Tags: google-chrome, https, certificate, x509, san

We are creating a CA signed certificate for us to talk to some embedded controller via HTTPS

If we just include a common name, Chrome flags it as insecure, but allows us to click through.

However if we add the following SAN entries in a config file

```
[alt_names] 
IP.1   = 192.168.61.30 
IP.2   = 192.168.61.31 
IP.3   = 192.168.61.32
```

Chrome complains that information is not consistent with the server and therefore it is unsafe to access the server page.

We got around it by adding another SAN entry as follows

```
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
IP.1   = 192.168.61.30
IP.2   = 192.168.61.31
IP.3   = 192.168.61.32
```

Then Chrome accepts the certificate and we can access the web page with no errors

What is the DNS.1 entry doing and why is it needed?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't information on how the access is being made to the server.
I'm guessing that you are trying to access it as https://localhost:, right?

Anyway, the Chrome browser will try to match the hostname you are accessing with all SAN attributes and with the CN of the server's certificate.

If it can't match with any of those attributes, then it will trigger an insecurity error, because Chrome can't trust in the server credential provided.

Comment: The url used to access is "https: //192.168.61.30"

Comment: You shouldn't need the localhost in this case.